# Implement Set Flow and Extrude Edges

Tags: modeling, workflow, extrude

I'm moving from 3Ds Max to Blender. I have two extremely serious questions for Blender's vital tools.

1- Why, by default Blender didn’t the  implement a tool similar to Set Flow in 3Ds Max? In Blender, this tool is implemented very strangely and does not work as easily as in 3Ds Max.

2 - Why is the extrud of edges in Blender so different from 3Ds Max ?? There is no way to adjust the force and type of bevel, instead  in the Blender simply pull one polygon, and this is very annoying.

I know similar topics have already been raised, but the absence of such critical tools cannot be ignored. I`ll be very glad if these requirements are passed on to the developers and in the next update they will take these remarks into account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is speculation about development decisions and feature requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender isn't trying to be 3Ds Max clone, so some feature may be implemented in a different way. That being said both problems can be solved in Blender without a lot of problems.

For your first problem you will need the LoopTools, which you can enable in *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*. Take a look at the following arc which has badly distributed vertices. Select the inner edge loop vertices and press *Space* in the loop tools to evenly distribute them.

[image]
[image]

Regarding your second issue, Blender separates extrude and bevel operations. You simply have to extrude first and then bevel. The result will likely be the same to what you expect from 3Ds Max. [Custom bevel profiles are currently in development](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/gsoc-2019-custom-bevel-profiles/7214).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but you gave an example of extrude polygon and not edges